# Android ) Build.gradle for GcmSender.java

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to make an app using GCM.

But something I can't do is there.

I have two build.gradles(one for project , one for app) but at the sample project of GCM provided by google, there are three build.gradles one more for GcmSender.java
It says below :

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmsender.GcmSender"

run {
    def params = []
    if (project.hasProperty('msg')) {
        params.add(project.msg)
        if (project.hasProperty('to')) {
            params.add(project.to)
        }
    }
    args params
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
}
```

And One more package just for GcmSender class, watch this picture below :
[image]

But I created GcmSender class at App Project...
Is it possibly making a problem?
Actually I'm in some issues for gradle and google_play_service issue

Comment: Where the google project ur using? Take look at this repo: https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android/gcm-demo it would help